# Error update trigger after new row has inserted into same table

Tags: sql-server, acumatica

I want to update OrigOrderNbr and OrigOrderType (QT type) because when I create first both of column are Null value. But after S2 was created (QT converted to S2) the OrigOrderType and OrigOrderNbr (S2) take from QT reference. Instead of that, I want to update it to QT also.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ipFa.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6qzT.png

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgg_SOOrder
    ON dbo.SOOrder
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    DECLARE @tOrigOrderType char(2),
            @tOrigOrderNbr nvarchar(15) 
    SELECT  @tOrigOrderType = i.OrderType,
            @tOrigOrderNbr = i.OrderNbr 
    FROM inserted i

    UPDATE dbo.SOOrder 
    SET OrigOrderType = @tOrigOrderType,
        OrigOrderNbr = @tOrigOrderNbr 
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE dbo.SOOrder.CompanyID='2' 
    and   dbo.SOOrder.OrderType=i.OrigOrderType 
    and   dbo.SOOrder.OrderNbr=i.OrigOrderNbr 
GO
```

After I run that trigger, it showed the message 'Error #91: Another process has updated 'SOOrder' record. Your changes will be lost.'.

Comment: The trigger runs on every insert, but you only want it to run on insert of S2 type record, correct?

Comment: No, what I mean is when I convert the quotation (QT) to SOOrder (S2) it alert message error. So it means I was updating and inserting same time.

Comment: Type S2 was inserted but I want to update is QT.

Comment: I thought QT is inserted first, then at some point later there is a conversion to S2 - why is it happening at the same time?

Comment: I think my trigger code maybe not check with the condition that I want to update QT but it updates S2 that just inserted instead.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw: you assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, the trigger fires **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @tOrigOrderNbr = i.OrderNbr FROM inserted i` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: @marc_s  I think the application here guarantees a single insert (via stored proc). This is a follow up question; OP had a prior post that explained the logic involved, where I suggested either a stored procedure / code modification, or a trigger, either one fitting the specific case. Would you agree this trigger is ok if the insert us handled via a stored proc, one record at a time?

Comment: @CoolBots: I would still never write a trigger like that - what if that logic changes some day? Suddenly, all the triggers break.... write them **properly** from the beginning, and you'll never get into trouble!

Comment: @marc_s Generally agreed; this is best handled by the procedure doing the insert of S2 record vs a trigger. I made that suggestion in my original answer (different post, same poster). I included code to check for multiple rows and throw an error as an active reminder of this rather unusual situation. If you have further improvements, please suggest an edit. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per long string of comments, including some excellent suggestions in regards to proper trigger writing techniques by @marc_s and @Damien_The_Unbeliever, as well as my better understanding of your issue at this point, here's the re-worked trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgg_SOOrder
ON dbo.SOOrder
FOR INSERT
AS

--Update QT record with S2 record's order info
UPDATE  SOOrder
SET     OrigOrderType       =   'S2'
,       OrigOrderNbr        =   i.OrderNbr
FROM    SOOrder                 dest
JOIN    inserted                i
ON      dest.OrderNbr       =   i.OrigOrderNbr
WHERE   dest.OrderType      =   'QT'
AND     i.OrderType         =   'S2'
AND     dest.CompanyID      =   2   --Business logic constraint
AND     dest.OrigOrderNbr   IS  NULL
AND     dest.OrigOrderType  IS  NULL
```

Basically, the idea is to update any record of type "QT" once a matching record of type "S2" is created. Matching here means that OrigOrderNbr of S2 record is the same as OrderNbr of QT record. I kept your business logic constraint in regards to CompanyID being set to 2. Additionally, we only care to modify QT records that have OrigOrderNbr and OrigOrderType set to `NULL`.

This trigger does not rely on a single-row insert; it will work regardless of the number of rows inserted - which is far less likely to break down the line.

Comment: Erorr: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tgg_SOOrder, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "i.OrigOrderType" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tgg_SOOrder, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "i.OrigOrderNbr" could not be bound.

Comment: @Elina sorry, my bad, fixed it... I removed the `FROM inserted i`, but forgot to swap the column names to variables

Comment: @Elina I updated the answer - the check should be for S2, not QT

Comment: This takes a broken trigger (`inserted` can contain *multiple* rows) and makes it *more* broken by assuming it can perform an `IF` test, ignoring the fact that *some* rows may have `S2` and some rows may not.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think the application here guarantees a single insert (via stored proc). This is a follow up question; OP had a prior post that explained the logic involved, where I suggested either a stored procedure / code modification, or a trigger, either one fitting the specific case. Would you agree this trigger is ok if the insert us handled via a stored proc, one record at a time?

Comment: Great result! but it's updated my S2 to replace of OrigOrderType and OrigOrderNbr (S2).

Comment: @Elina right, my bad again, sorry - the variable `@tOrigOrderType` now has the value of "S2", due to the `IF` statement. I updated my answer.

Comment: @CoolBots - no. A broken trigger is broken, even if you know that *today*, in your current circumstances, you're not going to trip over that broken behaviour. Because you have no way of knowing how circumstances may change in the future and suddenly you're seeing multi-row inserts and, six months down the line, someone starts wondering why some of your data is wrong. If you *must* write a "single-insert only" trigger, then as a service to yourself and others, you should at least check for multiple rows and create a big obnoxious error that stops things working.

Comment: Wait, I clear my data and test it. So wait for the result.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever agreed; I modified my answer to check for multiple rows. This would prevent the trigger from running on batch inserts, while still allowing the insert, and making the situation known. Please suggest an edit if you have further improvements to this case. Thank you!

Comment: @CoolBots, nothing changed. Because it still no updating in type QT.

Comment: I would probably do the check for single record *before* actually selecting anything from `Inserted` ....

Comment: @Elina what is CompanyID = 2? That column is not in your original post or image link - can it be removed? Or can you verify that CompanyID is in fact 2 for the records in question?

Comment: @CoolBots, in my system for the CompanyID='2' it means the current company that I'm working on. Because if I have backup in SQL Server it will generate my companyID to -100020002. So I want to work with only data of current company that's why I put condition CompanyID='2'.

Comment: @Elina, can you please verify that the QT record is actually inserted with CompanyID = 2? If it is, i am somewhat out of ideas... You don't happen to have SQL Server Profiler handy, do you?

Comment: @CoolBots, I check my sqlserver and the new record of QT really added into table and the S2 also added, but the OrigOrderType and OrigOrderNbr of QT still NULL.

Comment: @CoolBots, you know if I update direct by sql statement it changed correctly. So the reason I'm sure is the wrong condition that we wrote.

Comment: @Elina, it is very strange, it should work. Something else is happening with this insert - you need to look into how the insert is being done (it might be an insert followed by an update, etc). SQL Profiler would help greatly, as you can see the SQL statements as they come in. I am out of ideas, at least for now...

Comment: I have no idea too for now.

Comment: @Elina can you manually insert both QT and S2 records (one at a time), and add a `PRINT 'Test'` statement inside the `IF` statement in the trigger to see if it hits? Basically, I think something else is happening when your application is doing the insert...

Comment: @CoolBots, I added the PRINT 'Test' statement inside the IF statement as you told me. But It didn't alert so it means it not process in IF statement in the trigger.

Comment: @Elina did you try to *manually* do the inserts (not through your application)?

Comment: @CoolBots, I created new table and added new trigger there, after I inserted record one by one yet it didn't work too. Maybe I make some mistake then.

Comment: @Elina can you please add `PRINT 'OrigOrderType: ' + @tOrigOrderType` in the trigger, *above the `IF` statement*, and tell me the result after you insert the S2 record. Do the inserts manually, please.

Comment: Yes, I inserted it manually and the result Type QT was updated but it took the OrderType and OrderNbr of QT to insert in OrigOrderType and OrigOrderNbr of QT instead not S2.

Comment: @Elina what was the result of the PRINT (it'll be in the "Messages" tab of the result pane

Comment: @CoolBots, OrigOrderType: S2

Comment: @Elina wait, I thought those fields were NULL in the QT record - so are they staying NULL? Can you please post an image showing the QT record before and after the S2 insertion, and show which fields are wrong, and what the values should be?

Comment: @CoolBots, first before converting to S2, OrigOrderType and OrigOrderNbr of QT are NULL that's true. But after creating trigger and insert it manually it was updated in OrigOrderType and OrigOrderNbr of QT. As the picture I was updated in my question above.

Comment: @Elina I see, did you want the NULLs in QT record to update to 'S2' and OrderNumber from S2?

Comment: @Elina I think I have a better understanding of your problem now. I am going to completely re-write the trigger later tonight.

Comment: @CoolBots, sorry I'm sure I explain you unwell.

Comment: @Elina, I updated my answer; I tested this code, and I believe it accomplishes the result you're looking for.